# UIImageView not positioning correctly in Navbar and Status Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, navigation, frame

I am trying to use an Image in my Navigation Bar.  Keep getting close but no cigar.  With the code below, it loads the image fine and positions it nearly correct.  It appears to have a pad around the view, but I have no constraints around it.  When I remove the Status bar it shrinks the image but positions it fine within the NavBar.

```
    let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

    for parent in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
        for childView in parent.subviews {
            if(childView is UIImageView) {
                childView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }

    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    let SBheight = app.statusBarFrame.size.height
    let totalheight = SBheight + nav!.frame.height
    let totalwidth = nav!.frame.width
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: totalwidth , height: totalheight))
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill

    var image = UIImage(named: "HRC")
    imageView.image = image

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Here is the shot of the NavBar Area:

[image: Nav Image Not Placing Correctly.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can set the background picture of a navigation bar with no issue with the code below.

**Swift 3.0**

```
let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "name_of_background_image")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .stretch)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .default)
```

**Swift 2.3**

```
let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "name_of_background_image")?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .Stretch)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

You can add the code above to `viewDidLoad`, and customize the background image for each viewController.

Make sure you render the image as `Original` from the asset catalog.

[image]

And double check if your image has the right size.

@2x -> 750 x 128

@3x -> 1125 x 192

Comment: thanks.  I had to change "for: .default" to "forBarMetrics: Default" ... Now works well on iphones except landscape.  And IPads repeat and tile the image.  Any help on how to simply center or aspectFill the imge?